# arabic parenthesis reversed order

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, arabic

in my winform application i have datagridview displaying arabic data, but the value with parenthesis displays reversed parenthsis:

حدود ( دولية، بلدية، قطعة ارض  )

in english it means:

Boundary (International, Municipality, Block)

how to correct the order of parenthesis?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

Comment: thanx hans, i got the reason, but can you plz tell how to implement this in vb.net

Comment: how can i declare RLM  in datagridview cell string